# The type or namespace name 'Driver' does not exist in the namespace 'MongoDB'

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a library that uses the C# MongoDB Driver.
On my first computer, everything works without problems. On my second machine, I can't compile my library.

The error message states:

> The type or namespace name 'Driver' does not exist in the namespace
>   'MongoDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have checked that the library was successfully loaded by NuGet and also tried to manually add the references without success.

If I try to type the using statement, the IntelliSense suggests the  MongoDB.Driver namespace.

I tried it with the MongoDB Driver 2.7.3, 2.10 and 2.10.1 with none of them it works.

It shows correctly in my References in Visual Studio 2012

What could be the problem? Are there further configuration steps needed to run MongoDB.Driver with C#?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the .Net Framework version of the project.

I was using the .NetFramework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013 with MongoDB.Driver 2.9.2.0 and i received the same error.

[image: Error Image]

Though the reference link [MongoDB .NetFramework version](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) mentions that MongoDB.Driver v 2.7 and above supports in .Net 4.5 and above did not work in my case.

Once i changed the .Net Framework of the Project to 4.7.2 it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Interesting. The project requires the .Net Framework 4.5, so I am bound to that. I have checked the Framework on both machines(and in my project for that matter) and both are using .Net Framework 4.5. But since it works on one of the two machines I would rule the .Net Framework out.